# Backing up Riak Data when changing backends

Tags: nosql, riak

I have Riak (1.0.2) installed in my VMWare Workstation running Ubuntu Linux Natty. It's a single machine installation and not a cluster.

I changed my backend from BitCask to LevelDB to take advantage of secondary indices. However, now all my other data is inaccessible (I'm sure it's still there, just probably not compatible with the new backend).

How can I backup Riak data and make it accessible between backends?!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this e-mail thread, the most straightforward solution is to add a new node with the leveldb backend, keep the existing bitcask-backed node running and do a list-keys request that will perform read repair or hinted handoff, it's not clear which. Once the data is migrated, shut down the old node.

The key here is that Riak will not automatically convert the data between backends for you, which I think is good behaviour.

Also, you may want to use the multi backend for different buckets, but secondary indexing doesn't work with it, yet.

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.riak.user/5951

Comment: This [ServerFault question](http://serverfault.com/questions/348936/how-can-i-back-up-and-restore-data-from-a-riak-cluster) might also be helpful.